# Transfer img (file) to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with element

```
<input type="file" id="dialog-select-files"  multiple="" accept="image/jpeg" name='files[]'>
```

After a user chooses files I want to load a new page with a gallery of selected photos. 
So on my first page, I created URL, this way

```
URL.createObjectURL(files[i])
```

and saved it in cookies.

On my second page, I got URLs from cookies, created element 'img' and showed it on page:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = getCookie(nameCookie);
gallery.appendChild(img);
```

But URL is blob URL, like 
blob:http://localhost/8b67533a-f5f1-4529-8c3e-9829e6786be3 and it is not found on my second page.

How should I pass selected files from one page to another? I think I should use another way (not save in cookie), but I can't find a solution on the internet.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use sessionStorage, or localStorage for this propuses https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Galina Is there a reason why you can't use server side? I discourage sessionStorage and/or localStorage because they have a limit on the size, and multiple images can easy exceed that limit.

Comment: Nick, you mean this?
On the first page: I sent files to server
On server: create files links
On the second page: I do GET request to the server and get links?

I don't have a reason not using server side, 
I'm learning and I didn't think it is a better way.

Thank you for your answer, I'll try to use server side.

Comment: @GalinaNiukhalova do you already have the images on your server? Are they stored somewhere on your server or are they in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to base64 string, then you can save it in the cookies or in the localStorage or in the sessionStorage and get it ftom there.

```
function img2base64(imgSrc, cb) {
  var img = new Image();
  // formats: image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/bmp
  var outputFormat = 'image/png';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    cb(dataURL);
  };
  img.src = imgSrc;
}

var base64Str;
img2base64(imgSrc, function(dataUrl) {
   // do something
   console.log(dataUrl);
   base64Str = dataUrl;
   localStorage.setItem('img1', dataUrl);
});
```